# How to make statement that does more than 2 if condition is completed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement

I'm making a Windows vb.net form application in Visual Studio 2015, where user can either preview an image in a PictureBox by importing it from a file dialog browser, or from a web url. If the user chooses to import it from its computer using the file dialog, the preview will automatically load once it has selected the image file.
If user accidentally fills both url and file dialog, i want to clear the TextBox of the url (called url_cover), the TextBox displaying the name of file imported in file dialog (called Browse.FileName) and the PictureBox preview (called preview), and also display a MessageBox telling user to try again, using only one of the import options.

I've already tried making a basic if statement which (until there everything normal) :

```
If url_cover.Text <> Nothing And Browse.FileName <> Nothing Then
MsgBox("Please do not import image using both file browser and URL.", [vbOKOnly], "Warning") 
url_cover.Clear() Browse.FileName = Nothing preview.Enabled = False
```

I was expecting all these things to happen if i filled both url and file browser, but i came out with an error telling me that an end of statement was expected after the second instruction (which is url_cover.Clear()). 
I tried switching the order in which the three instructions had to be executed, but every time it was the same, after the second instruction, an end of statement was expected... 
Hope my explanations have been clear, and my question is how can i execute more than 2 instructions after the condition of my If statement has been completed.

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for comment. Yes but this doesnt give me an error and it isn't the core of my question sorry 

Comment: 'end of statement' or 'End If statement' ?

Comment: @PhilM end of statement.

Comment: I think you need to copy/paste the exact error message (edit the question to include it)

Comment: Thanks everyone, i figured out how to process :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out... You can use `:` to separate statements if you want them on one line.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(url_cover.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Browse.FileName) Then MsgBox("Please do not import image using both file browser and URL.", [vbOKOnly], "Warning") : url_cover.Clear() : Browse.FileName = String.Empty : preview.Enabled = False
```

Or block...

```
If url_cover.Text <> Nothing And Browse.FileName <> Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Please do not import image using both file browser and URL.", [vbOKOnly], "Warning") 
    url_cover.Clear()
    Browse.FileName = Nothing
    preview.Enabled = False
End If
```

IMHO, look into [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Multiple statements in one line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#putting-multiple-statements-on-one-line) and the [AndAlso operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//operators/andalso-operator). Also try to avoid the `:`, if statements can become long, obscure readability etc, but nothing is wrong in using it.

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: Thank you @Çöđěxěŕ, this helped ! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than one statement to execute if a condition is met, then you need to enclose it in a block that ends with `End If`.

Your code will only execute the messagebox if the conditions are satisfied and then try to execute the rest whether the condition is met or not. You're getting the `End Of Statement Expected` error because you're trying to put several statements on one line.

Try this ..

```
If url_cover.Text <> Nothing And Browse.FileName <> Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Please do not import image using both file browser and URL.", [vbOKOnly],  Warning") 
    url_cover.Clear()
    Browse.FileName = Nothing
    preview.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: yes, this is the right solution, thanks @David Wilson :)

Comment: So much easier to read and comprehend. The one liner is for C# :-)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The smiley face following that comment was meant to imply that it was a joke. Sorry. I did here a rumor that in the next version of C# you would be able to write the entire Excel application in a single line. Not to be left behind the Visual Studio team is removing the break point from the debugger. :-)